# Is there any wrong in my object relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, entity-relationship

I want which order have different order status, so I have a table called "status", in the status.rb, it likes this:

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order 
  attr_accessible :name

end
```

And this is my order.rb:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :statuses
end
```

In my view, I try to call the related status like this:

```
    <%= order.statuses.name%>
```

It don't work, so , I called it in this way:

```
<% order.statuses.each_with_index do |order_status, index| %>
<%= order_status.name%>
<% end %>
```

It still don't work. I have the error like this:

> uninitialized constant Order::Statuses

I changed my code to this:

It should be

has_one :status

and

order.status.name

But I have this error:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: statuses.order_id: SELECT * FROM "statuses" WHERE ("statuses".order_id = 5)  LIMIT 1

I only want the order related to the status, but the status is not related to the order, can I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting an error because of pluralization. You should have:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :status
end
```

**However**, it sounds like you might have the belongs_to - has_one relationship backwards. If you only want to have only a few statuses in the database (eg: pending, billed, shipped, complete), a Status should `has_many` orders, and each Order should `belongs_to` a Status. The way you have it set up now, there will be a separate Status object for each Order. This may be what you want, but make sure you understand that it implies that every status is different (maybe each is a sentence or two describing the order).

Answer (score 1):

It should be

has_one :status

and

order.status.name

Ruby on Rails has built-in pluralizing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined relationship as `has_one` you just should use it in singular form: `order.status.name`